# Assembly issue with '[' in x86 syntax for GCC

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, att, intel-syntax

to make it short: when I am trying to assemble my code I get this
`Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 '[esp+4]'`
and
`Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 1 '[edx]'`

The most relevant code is already in the error, however I got the code from [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupts_tutorial). To reproduce the error just use this little pattern in `.section .text` with the command shown below:

```
mov edx, [esp + 4]
lidt [edx]
sti
ret
```

I'm using `gcc -m32 -c -o idtasm.o idtasm.S` to assemble.

Comment: That is not gnu assembler syntax. You will need to adjust it. With that file you might get away with passing `-masm=intel` and changing `global` to `.global` (with a dot) and deleting all the `extern` lines. Or, you could just use `nasm` which that code was probably intended for.

Comment: Thank you. I used `nasm -f elf -o idtasm.o idtasm.S` and it worked!

Comment: @G3bE Very good! Post this as an answer to your own question so other people notice.

Comment: That looks valid for the GNU assembler with `.intel_syntax noprefix`, but it's of course not valid AT&T syntax (the default for GAS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Jester I found a solution: the assembly code was written for nasm so used it with this command: `nasm -f elf -o idtasm.o idtasm.S` -f elf is replacing gcc's -c **and** -m32 if I understood everything right.

Comment: Yup, NASM's `-f elf` is a synonym for `-f elf32`, not `-f elf64` even on 64-bit systems where GCC's default is `-m64`.  And NASM is just an assembler, like `as --32`, it won't ever run the linker for you like the `gcc` front-end will.  (Which is why you need `-c` to *not* do that, just invoke a compiler and/or the GNU assembler.)